# Is application US20090055029 this fairly obvious?

Tags: prior-art-request, patentability, software, examination, us20090055029

This is basically "put a webserver on it and call it an invention"

This sort of thing has been done on home routers and numerous other types of industrial equipment for many years.

How would one go about killing this application once and for all?

Answer (score 1):

This application is currently awaiting appeal. It has been rejected and amended/argued a few times and now the applicants have filed an 18 page appeal brief that has been responded to by an equally long examiner's response. There is a very long wait right now for a case to get before the board.

As they sit right now the claims are:

[image]

The examiner's reply lists these as the references cited against it:

[image]

Ward and Gibbs are cited as the most important references.